# Grey out everything but fancybox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to follow [this](http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-simple-screen-grey-effect-jquery/) simple tutorial regarding the standard grey out/popup display used in many website.

Ironically enough, this looks decent enough in IE but in Chrome I can't quite get the look I want. Right now everything, including the pop up, is greyed out. How can I alter the jquery/css so everything on the screen is greyed out except the fancybox pop up?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc0q57nz/

**jQuery**

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').css({ opacity: 0.5, 'width':$(document).width(),'height':$(document).height()});

            //Determine which links to show in navbar
            window.onload = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("CheckSecurity", "Home")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data == "viewer" || data == "NA") {
                            $('#Review').hide();
                            $('.Admin').hide();
                        } else if (data == "modifier") {
                            $('.Admin').hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

            var display = "<div id='fancycontainer' style='padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px'><h1 style='margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:0px;'>Monet has moved!</h1>" +
                "<p>Click the link below if you are not redirected momentarily. To add the new page as a bookmark please click <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='BookmarkMe()'>here</a></p>" +
                "<a href='http://insideshared.dev.com/Monet/'>Click here</a></div>";

            $.fancybox(display, {
                fitToView: false,
                autoScale: true,
                autoDimension: true,
                closeClick: true,
                openEffect: 'fade',
                closeEffect: 'fade',
                closeBtn: true,
                openSpeed: 'fast',
                closeSpeed: 'fast'
            }).css({ 'display': 'block', 'z-index': '-1' });
        });

        function BookmarkMe() {
            var bookmarkUrl = "http://insideshared.symetra.com/Monet/";
            var bookmarkTitle = this.title;

            if (/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) { //For Chrome
                alert('Chrome does not support this function. Please bookmark the page once redirected.');
                return false;
            } else if (window.sidebar) { // For Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
                window.sidebar.addPanel(bookmarkTitle, bookmarkUrl, "");
            } else if (window.external || document.all) { // For IE Favorite
                window.external.AddFavorite(bookmarkUrl, bookmarkTitle);
            } else if (window.opera) { // For Opera Browsers
                $("#bookmarkme").attr("href", bookmarkUrl);
                $("#bookmarkme").attr("title", bookmarkTitle);
                $("#bookmarkme").attr("rel", "sidebar");
            } else { // for other browsers which does not support
                alert('Your browser does not support this bookmark action. Please ');
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
    <body>
        @using Monet.Common
        <div class="page">  
            @Html.Partial("NavBarPartial")
            <section id="main">
                <div id="content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>          
        <div id="footer">
            <span style="color: Gray;"> </span>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? It seems a bootstrap modal would work fine.

Comment: This is an internal site for a company that uses IE as their standard. I am trying to learn something by figuring this out.

Comment: Good luck then. Perhaps you should "inspect element" on your tutorial's background and check out the source code.

Comment: i thought fancybox had a `modal:true` option which did this for you

Comment: There is quite an amount of overkill here imo. Why not just do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2mrkh310/1/

Comment: @Rhumborl - I briefly looked in the documentation and wasn't able to find anything. I set the `model:true` property as well, didn't see any change.

Comment: @ScottRowell - any idea why this is happening?

Comment: By changing `$('body').css({ opacity: 0.5,` to `$('.page').css({ opacity: 0.5,`, that will stop the popup box from being greyed out.